# screenshot attached in Extent report not shown in Bamboo artifacts though it works fine locally

Tags: selenium-webdriver, extentreports, bamboo-artifacts

I have Extent report and Screen shot taken for the failed cases saved under TARGET folder. When I run my code locally all looks fine and I see screenshots attached in the extent report but when I run the same code through Bamboo I don't see the screen shots.

using the below copy pattern and the location I can see screen shots and the report separately but report does not have the screenshots. Can someone help me here ?

Name                                    Location                               Copy/Pattern
Extent Report                        UI/target                            /Execution_Report.html
screenshots                          UI/target                                   /*.png

Comment: Bamboo workspace path context?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your question. When I check the user directory and the path where the screen shots are saving are correct.